# Apache spark: How do we split RDD[v] into Map[k,RDD[v]]?

Tags: api, apache-spark

The groupByKey gives me  RDD[key,value] And I could not find any way to convert this to Map[key,RDD[values]] .
Thanks.

SV

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a RDD into two or more RDDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970709/how-to-split-a-rdd-into-two-or-more-rdds)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no Spark primitive that would allow you to split an RDD by key like that.  We are using filtering to achieve a similar result.  And performance-wise it has to be a lot lighter than an actual `groupByKey`, because filter does not require a shuffle.

```
val keys = rdd.keys.collect
val dataByKey = keys.map(key => (key, rdd.filter(_._1 == key)).toMap
```

Note that the keys have to fit in the memory of the driver for this to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding to my query. I will try your suggestion.