# In spark what is an efficient way to process 2 sub-groups in an RDD without filtering the RDD twice?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a large RDD.  I need to group it into two sets.  The first set I need to store to disk, the second set I would need to process further then store to disk.  Right now I'm achieving that with 2 filters.  I thought about using a group by but not sure how that would help (in fact it may even cause a lot of unnecessary shuffling).

---

Let's assume I have the following `JavaPairRDD<Boolean, SomeClass> rdd` let's assume that record that have `true` key compose 99% of rdd.  Furthermore let's assume that rdd is large.

- I need to store the records that have `false` value on disk.
- I need to do further processing with records that have `true` value.

I could do the following (psudo-code)

```
JavaPairRDD<Boolean, SomeClass> truthy = rdd.filter(selectTrueKeys());
JavaPairRDD<Boolean, SomeClass> falsy = rdd.filter(selectFalseKeys());

falsy
    .map(prepareForStorage())
    .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration());

truthy
    .map(mapToSomethingElse())
    .combineByKey(create, combine, merge)
    .map(prepareForStorage())
    .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataSet(job.getConfiguration());
```

It seems wasteful to filter the entire set twice.  I thought about grouping the `rdd` by key.  But I don't think that will help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a RDD into two or more RDDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970709/how-to-split-a-rdd-into-two-or-more-rdds)