# How to divide dataset in two parts based on filter in Spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to divide DF in two parts using single filter operation.For example

let say df has below records

```
UID    Col
 1       a
 2       b
 3       c
```

if I do

```
df1 = df.filter(UID <=> 2)
```

can I save filtered and non-filtered records in different RDD in single operation
?

```
 df1 can have records where uid = 2
 df2 can have records with uid 1 and 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're interested only in saving data you can add an indicator column to the `DataFrame`:

```
val df = Seq((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")).toDF("uid", "col")
val dfWithInd = df.withColumn("ind", $"uid" <=> 2)
```

and use it as a partition column for the `DataFrameWriter` with one of the supported formats (as for 1.6 it is Parquet, text, and JSON):

```
dfWithInd.write.partitionBy("ind").parquet(...)
```

It will create two separate directories (`ind=false`, `ind=true`) on write.

In general though, it is not possible to yield multiple `RDDs` or `DataFrames` from a single transformation. See [How to split a RDD into two or more RDDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32970709/1560062)