# How to split a rdd into 2 based on column name

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have an RDD of two columns A and B
How can i create 2RDD's out if it?

I have a use case where i am taking an input RDD, performs some operations and produces two different output (intermediate (column A), final(column B)) which needs to be 2 ifferent locations. How can i split them?

Thanks

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23995040/1560062 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/32970709/1560062