# In Spark, how can I split one DataFrame to two DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one big data of DataFrame A.

I want to apply some filter to that and make a DataFrame B, and make another DataFrame C for not filtered data.

In summary, it's similar to following pseudo code.

```scala
A.foreach(_ => {
  if (isFiltered(_)) addToDF_B()
  else addToDF_C()
})
```

And, B and C will be written to different tables.

I tried to filter B firstly and use A.except(B) to make C, but it doesn't work if scheme has complex type(map or array).

Except filtering twice, is any other way to do it at once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is worth linking, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970709/how-do-i-split-an-rdd-into-two-or-more-rdds For RDDs no good, native way exists, but with additional libraries or by hacking partitions, it becomes possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple `.filter` api on `dataframe` `A` as

```
val A = Seq(
  (1, 22),
  (2, 11),
  (10, 3),
  (20, 4)
).toDF("col1", "col2")

A.show(false)
```

You should have `A` `dataframe` as

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1   |22  |
|2   |11  |
|10  |3   |
|20  |4   |
+----+----+
```

Define your filter as

```
def filter = col("col1") < 10
```

And apply them to have different `dataframes` as

```
val B = A.filter(filter)
B.show(false)
```

Output is

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1   |22  |
|2   |11  |
+----+----+
```

And your `C` `dataframe` is opposite of `B` `dataframe` as

```
val C = A.filter(!filter)
C.show(false)
```

Output is

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|10  |3   |
|20  |4   |
+----+----+
```

Comment: Sorry. Like I mentioned 'Except filtering twice', I'm asking better way.

Comment: For creating two dataframes, I guess you will have to do two operations, if not filter twice then filter once and other opeation once.

Comment: Thanks. I wish there would be something like 'switch-case', but it looks no way for now.

Comment: There is match case. but that would be difficult to implement in your requirements.

Comment: didn't the answer helped you @JaycePark? if it did you should consider accepting and upvote . if not you can downvote and I shall delete the post

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it using SparkSql

```
val A = Seq(
  (1, 22),
  (2, 11),
  (10, 3),
  (20, 4)
).toDF("col1", "col2")

A.show(false)

val B = spark.sql(select * from A /*where = your condition for B*/) //spark is SparkSession or SQLContext
val C = spark.sql(select * from A /*where = your condition for C*/) //spark is SparkSession or SQLContext
```