# How can I group pairRDD by keys and turn the values into RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

So what I have is `RDD[(String, Int)]` and I need to convert it into `Map[String, RDD[Int]]`

Ex.

My input looks like this:

```
RDD[("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1), ("c", 3)]
```

And the output I'm trying to get is:

```
Map["a" -> RDD[1, 2], "b" -> RDD[1], "c" -> RDD[3]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the use case for this exactly?

Comment: @mtoto Its for analyzing a bunch of hashtags and their popularity (in terms of the like/fav count). Pairs are in the format (Tag, Like). The output of this is going to be clustered with the k-means algorithm.

Comment: don't think you are going to be able cluster anything in map object that contains distributed data as values