# Return multiple RDD in a simple run of map operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx

I am now doing some operations using GraphX and want something like this

```
val ans = graph.triplets.map(
    e => {
        if (conditon1){
            return ans_1 to RDD_1
        }
        else (condition2){
            return ans_2 to RDD_2
        }
    }
)
```

I know I can use double runs of `graph.triplets.map` to return 2 different RDD, like this

```
val RDD_1 = graph.triplets.map(
    e => {
        if (conditon1){
            return ans_1
        }
    })
val RDD_2 = graph.triplets.map(
    e => {
        if (condition2){
            return ans_2
        }
    })
```

However in order to improve the efficiency I want to do it in a single run as I depicted above. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan If so, how can I create this kind of tuple, what is its structure? Because RDD_1 and RDD_2 are not the same size.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I added the 2 runs version, it is obviously slower because we have run one more traversal

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Must it have a else expression? The official example of Spark does not, in `spark/examples/graphx/AggregateMessagesExample.scala`

Comment: why don't you use filter instead of map. filter two times as you are doing with map. that would be more efficient than map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split an RDD into two or more RDDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970709/how-do-i-split-an-rdd-into-two-or-more-rdds)

Comment: @user9613318 thank you. But that is in Python and it is the Python's feature grammar. How can I use it in scala?

Comment: @Litchy I don't think that the code is that important there. More the conclusion, that you if want two RDDs, you'll need two separate transformations.