# Spark scala reduce multiple filtering possible on RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
def isSmallerScore(value:Int): Boolean ={
  val const = 200
  if(value < const) true else false
}
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Java", 100), ("Python", 200), ("Scala", 300)))
val result1: RDD[(String, Int)] = rdd.filter(x => isSmallerScore(x._2))
val result2: RDD[(String, Int)] = rdd.filter(x => !isSmallerScore(x._2))
```

From the above code using a filter, I have created two RDD. One is with the smaller score size and another RDD is with the higher score.
Here to separate it out I have done the filter action two times.

Is it possible to create in a single filter action? How can reduce another filter action to find out the result(either result1 or result2 )

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971246/14165730) says "it is not possible to yield multiple RDDs from a single transformation"

Comment: You mean it's not possible to avoid the same action(isSmallerScore) multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ETL like Informatica BDM, Talend, Pentaho et al. Where you have multiple pipelines running in parallel (branches) that you can create graphically.

You need to `cache` rdd and filter twice to get 2 RDDs.